# Hidden disabled year on MUI datepicker

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to hide the disabled year on MUI datepicker? Now I can only hide the button inside MUI div because there is no way to determine between divs.

```
<div class="PrivatePickersYear-root PrivatePickersYear-modeMobile css-k9reix">
  <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="PrivatePickersYear-yearButton css-m1gykc">2017</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that this is with respect to ReactJS, you can pass `views` prop to calendar component. It expects array of string. Try `views={['day','month']}`. Here is the API documentation. https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/

Comment: I mean i want to limit the range of selection ex: 2016-2022 and i want to hide other years

Comment: try setting `maxDate` and `minDate` prop to restrict user in date selection.

Comment: @Nik thanks this is setting `maxDate` and `minDate` is what i want